# Huge matrix multiplication

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-calculus, matrix-decomposition, sparse-matrices

I have a sparse A matrix stored in column major order (it is intrisically column major) of ~80GB and another sparse matrix B relatively small (1GB) which can be loaded in row or column major with no particular effort. I need to compute a straight matrix product S = AB. My problem is that I have only 64 GB of RAM (I usually use the Eigen c++ library ) and i need to compute the product by blocks.

I was thinking to re store the A matrix in row major (even it could imply a great increase in terms of storage) and later load the new matrix A by blocks, N rows at time, compute and store the various products and at the end assembly all the blocks together.

Do you have any better ideas?

Comment: Why does some calculate demonic matrix products like these?

Comment: the matrices come from the modelization of a PET scanner

Comment: @B.Pasternak [Quote](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication): "Computing matrix products is both a central operation in many numerical algorithms and potentially time consuming, making it one of the most well-studied problems in numerical computing."

Comment: Maybe https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/ is better suited than the math forum.

Answer (score 0):

Let A be of size m by n and B be of size n by k.  You might consider:

1. Store B by rows rather than columns.
2. Break up the A matrix into blocks of size m by n1.  Break up B into blocks of size n1 by k.
3. Multiply the blocks of A times the corresponding blocks of B, and then sum/merge the results to get AB in row major form.

Keep in mind that AB will be of size m by k and might be very dense.

Comment: What do you mean with "concatenate"? I should sum the various blocks to get AB, I think.

Comment: Yes, I meant that you should sum the results, but this actually requires merging the sparsity structures so it's non-trivial.

Comment: Ok, actually I di something very close to this solution with a previous smaller matrix, saving the "slices" to concatenate to disk. Now I need to sum the various blocks, but you really helped me to better understand the solution. Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 0):

Optimal matrix representation and multiplication algorithm is highly dependent on sparsity patterns of $A$, $B$ and $S$ matrices.

I assume, that all matrices are stored in the compressed column storage with sorted row indices.

For such huge matrix $A$ it is possible, that computing $A^T$ (i.e. converting the compressed column storage to the compressed row storage) can be too costly. But if possible, then one may compute $S' = B'A'$ simply by splitting $A' = \left[A_1', A_2',\dots, A_k'\right]$ and computing $B'A_i'$ for $i=1,\dots,k$ using the regular sparse-sparse matrix multiplication for matrices in CCS format. This can be faster, than computing $(A')'\times B$ (i.e. converting the matrix $A$ to the CRS storage first, and splitting the resulting matrix by rows), when $S$ is sparse, but slower, when $S$ is nearly dense.

I would consider the following algorithm:

1. store the matrix $A$ in the CCS format, but split it by rows, i.e. $A=\text{col}(A_1, A_2, \dots, A_k)$.
2. compute $S_i = A_iB$ by the regular sparse-sparse matrix multiplication algorithm for matrices in the CCS format.
3. assembly the matrix $S = \text{col}(S_1, S_2, \dots, S_k)$ if required.

If $S_i$ is too large to be stored in RAM, then the matrix $B$ should also be split by columns. This algorithm does not require costly matrix transpositions, required partitioning is quite cheap, IO data transfer is low.

Answer (score 0):

You can:

1. Assign for each element $S^i_j = \sum_\limits{k} A^i_k B^k_j$ the quantity of $n$ workers at some C++ or C parallel library of preference.
2. Operate in multi threads with several virtual machines either row, column, or another batch you may find suitable (It would require $n$ machines, which compete the respective workers);
3. IO operations take time, which is pretty much the throttle here. Save the result in some accessible format and indexable $(i, j)$ way;
4. Merge the results after it finishes.